# adding new div element with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I add the same   element (with the same id) by clicking a button that has javascript attached on onclick() (I have no JS at the moment)? I thought about using document.write and then just add a div, but didn't work out for me + I've heard it's a bad practice.

So far what I have:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html/>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>wat</title>
        <meta charset= "UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CssHtmlLapai.css">
        <script src="JsLapai.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button type="button" onclick="NewDiv()">Click me</button>
        <div id="first"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#first{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Having the same `ID` multiple times is indeed bad practice. An ID is used as an `unique identifier`. If you want an general identifier, You can use an `class`

Comment: please post the code of `NewDiv()` function. so that it will be easy to help.

Comment: could you be more specific please? Where should the div be added? Directly after the button? Also, do not use the same ID multiple times, it is not good practice. Use class instead.

Comment: @Mathlight - beat me too it.

Comment: using document.write is not a bad practice, in this case it is entirely wrong. You don't want to write new content, you want to -append- content to existing content. Consider using JQuery which makes DOM manipulation incredibly easy. http://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: Maybe you should read about dom manipulation with javascript (and jquery to make it easier) then try something, and then if you can't figure it out, ask a question here. -1

Answer (score 2):

Use `document.createElement(tagName)` to do this.

[**DOC**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement)

```
function NewDiv() {
   var newDiv = document.createElement("div");

   document.getElementById("parentDivId").appendChild(newDiv);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is applying the same CSS across multiple elements.  To do this you should use a class rather than a duplicate ID.  (IDs are inherently used as identifiers and javasript will do surprising things if you try to have multiple).

So instead of 'id' use 'class'

```
<!DOCTYPE html/>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>wat</title>
        <meta charset= "UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CssHtmlLapai.css">
        <script src="JsLapai.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button type="button" onclick="NewDiv()">Click me</button>
        <div class="first"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

To define a class you will use the '.' prefix

```
.first{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

And then in JS you could do something like...

```
<script>
    function NewDiv()
    {
        var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
        newDiv.className = "first";
        newDiv.id = "someotherid"; //not neccessary but probably useful
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following Code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html/>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>wat</title>
        <meta charset= "UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CssHtmlLapai.css">
        <script src="JsLapai.js"></script>
    </head>
       <body>
            <button type="button" id="click-me">Click me</button>
            <div id="first" class="common-css"></div>
        </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.common-css{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('click-me').onclick = function() {
   var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
   var firstdiv = document.getElementById('first');
   newdiv.setAttribute('class', 'common-css');
   firstdiv.appendChild(newdiv);
};
```

JSFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/vinoddalvi/u4H9h/

Answer (score -1):

you can use jquery:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $('#first').first().clone().appendTo('body');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/km8Wv/